# Three specific doubts about contact sensors

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The doubts are at the final.

INTRODUCTION:

I have a box with the contact sensor TAG:*

box_collision

This box is over the ground plane.

ANd i can see the sensor information with the instruction: gztopic echo /gazebo/default/box/link/my_contact

contact {

collision1: "box::link::box_collision"

collision2: "ground_plane::link::collision"

position {

```
x: -0.500000000462553
y: 0.49999999823938179
z: -1.3116396857526524e-11
```

}

position {

```
x: 0.499999999537447
y: 0.49999999830396458
z: -1.3116396855009743e-11
```

}

normal {
x: 0
y: 0
z: 1

}

normal {

```
x: 0
y: 0
z: 1
```

}

depth: 1.3116396857526524e-11

depth: 1.3116396855009743e-11

wrench {

```
body_1_name: "box::link::box_collision"
body_2_name: "ground_plane::link::collision"

body_1_force {

  x: 0.18159452738357906
  y: -0.58800230161463551
  z: 2.9400153496814356

}

body_2_force {

  x: 0
  y: 0
  z: 0

}

body_1_torque {
  x: 1.1760044494554212
  y: 1.3792103044659421
  z: 0.2032039939184285
}

body_2_torque {
  x: 0
  y: 0
  z: 0
}
```

}

wrench {

```
body_1_name: "box::link::box_collision"

body_2_name: "ground_plane::link::collision"

body_1_force {

  x: -0.18159452730762679
  y: -0.5880023016380882
  z: 2.9400153496814232
```

}

```
body_2_force {
  x: 0
  y: 0
  z: 0
}

body_1_torque {
  x: 1.1760044496335631
  y: -1.3792103043140376
  z: -0.20320399391842819
}

body_2_torque {
  x: 0
  y: 0
  z: 0
}
```

}

time {
sec: 29
nsec: 599000000
}
}

DOUBTS:

I have Three questions about the contact sensors:

1.Are the forces above(body 1 force  or body 2 force) , proportional to the contact force
between the bodies?

2.Is The value of the body_1_force  ZERO , if there is no contact?

3.How do I know if there is no contact  between the bodies(box and ground plane)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1467/three-specific-doubts-about-contact-sensors/) by [Jey_316](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/165/jey_316/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Please see [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/516/missing-documentation-on-contact-data) and [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/313/add-documentation-describing-data-returned/diff) and see if that helps with parts of your questions?

Also, please see [my answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1448/i-dont-understand-the-contact-sensor-data/?answer=1464#post-id-1464).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0